# Detect when a specific window in another process opens or closes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So I made a win app and I want it to pop in front of the screen whenever I open the "Page Setup" from notepad and close it whenever I close the notepad.

I tried this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("User32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int cmdShow);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hwnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]

public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
ManagementEventWatcher watcher;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace WHERE ProcessName = 'Notepad.exe'");
    var mew = new ManagementEventWatcher(query) { Query = query };
    mew.EventArrived += (sender, args) => { AppStarted(); };
    mew.Start();                       
}
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{     
    base.OnLoad(e);
    watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher("Select * From Win32_ProcessStopTrace");
    watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);
    watcher.Start();
}
protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    watcher.Stop();
    watcher.Dispose();
    base.OnFormClosed(e);
}
void watcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    // var _windowHandle = FindWindow(null, "Page Setup");
    if ((string)e.NewEvent["ProcessName"] == "notepad.exe")

    {
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
     {
         TopMost = false;
         Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1000, 1);
     });

    }

}
async void AppStarted()
{         
    await Task.Delay(300);
    BeginInvoke(new System.Action(PoPInFront));
}
void PoPInFront()
{
    var _notepadProcess = Process.GetProcesses().Where(x => x.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("notepad")).DefaultIfEmpty(null).FirstOrDefault();
    if (_notepadProcess != null)
    {
        var _windowHandle = FindWindow(null, "Page Setup");
        var _parent = GetParent(_windowHandle);
        if (_parent == _notepadProcess.MainWindowHandle)
        {
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                Location = new System.Drawing.Point(550, 330);
                TopMost = true;
            });
        }
    }

    //var ExternalApplication = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad").FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Page Setup"));     
    //Location = new System.Drawing.Point(550, 330);
    //TopMost = true;
}
```

Until now my app pops in front of the screen and sets `TopMost = true` whenever I open notepad,not the "Page Setup" of the notepad and it moves back to the corner of the screen whenever I close the notepad.

#### All I want to do is:

I would like to move the app to the center of the screen and set `TopMost = true` whenever the "Page Setup" is opened and back to the corner and `TopMost = false`  when the "Page Setup" is closed.

`Location = new System.Drawing.Point(550, 330);` - for center of the screen

`Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1000, 1);` - for corner

#### Edit:

I tried also this but no luck.

```
void PoPInFront()
        {
            //IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
            //foreach (Process pList in Process.GetProcesses())
            //{
            //    if (pList.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Page Setup"))
            //    {
            //        hWnd = pList.MainWindowHandle;
            //        Location = new System.Drawing.Point(550, 330);
            //        TopMost = true;
            //    }
            //}

            var ExternalApplication = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad").FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Page Setup"));     
            Location = new System.Drawing.Point(550, 330);
            TopMost = true;
        }
```

#### Edit 2:

I think the problem is here.I don't know how to do something like this:

```
var query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace WHERE ProcessName = 'Notepad.exe' AND MainWindowTitle = 'Page Setup'");
```

**`AND MainWindowTitle = 'Page Setup'`**

Comment: "Page setup" is the title of a dialog, not the main window of Notepad.  It will appear at a completely random time, you have no use whatsoever for Win32_ProcessStartTrace.  So best thing you can do with this code is to throw it away, it doesn't solve anything.  Not using UI Automation, ably exposed to C# through the System.Windows.Automation namespace, is never not a mistake.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140217-00/?p=1743

Comment: According to the Hans' comment, additional to using `SetWinEventHook`  I also added an example of using UI Automation APIs which is preferred.

Comment: [Archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190205004524/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140217-00/?p=1743)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use either of these options:

- Using SetWinEventHook method
- Handling UI Automation Events (Preferred) (Suggested by Hans in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241044/detect-when-a-specific-window-in-another-process-opens-detect-notepad-page-set#comment67829337_40241044))

**Solution 1 - Using SetWinEventHook method**

Using [`SetWinEventHook`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) you can listen to [some events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/event-constants?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) from other processes and  register a [`WinEventProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nc-winuser-wineventproc?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) callback method to receive the event when the event raised.

Here `EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND` can help us.

We limit the event receiver to receive this event from a specific process and then we check if the text of the window which causes the event is equals to `Page Setup` then we can say the `Page Setup` window in the target process is open, otherwise we can tell the `Page Setup` dialog is not open.

To keep things simple in below example I supposed a `notepad` instance is open when your application starts, but you can also use `Win32_ProcessStartTrace` to detect when a `notepad` application runs.

To be more specific and say when the dialog is closed, you can listen to `EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY` and detect if the message is for the window which we are interested in.

```
public const uint EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND = 0x0003;
public const uint EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY = 0x8001;
public const uint WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0;
public delegate void WinEventDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd,
    int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr
    hmodWinEventProc, WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess,
    uint idThread, uint dwFlags);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool UnhookWinEvent(IntPtr hWinEventHook);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);
```

```
IntPtr hook = IntPtr.Zero;
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    var p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault();
    if (p != null)
        hook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND,
        IntPtr.Zero, new WinEventDelegate(WinEventProc), 
        (uint)p.Id, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
}
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    UnhookWinEvent(hook);
    base.OnFormClosing(e);
}
void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType,
    IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
{
    string s = "Page Setup";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length + 1);
    GetWindowText(hwnd, sb, sb.Capacity);
    if (sb.ToString() == s)
        this.Text = "Page Setup is Open";
    else
        this.Text = "Page Setup is not open";
}
```

**Solution 2 - Handling UI Automation Events**

As suggested in comments by Hans, you can use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-clientportal?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) APIs to subscribe for `WindowOpenedEvent` and `WindowClosedEvent`.

In below example I supposed there is an open instance of `notepad` and detected opening and closing of its `Page Setup` dialog:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    var notepad = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")
                        .FirstOrDefault();
    if (notepad != null)
    {
        var notepadMainWindow = notepad.MainWindowHandle;
        var notepadElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(notepadMainWindow);
        Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(
            WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent, notepadElement,
            TreeScope.Subtree, (s1, e1) =>
            {
                var element = s1 as AutomationElement;
                if (element.Current.Name == "Page Setup")
                {
                    //Page setup opened.
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        this.Text = "Page Setup Opened";
                    }));
                    Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(
                        WindowPattern.WindowClosedEvent, element,
                        TreeScope.Subtree, (s2, e2) =>
                        {
                            //Page setup closed.
                            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                            {
                                this.Text = "Closed";
                            }));
                        });
                }
            });
    }
}
```

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Automation.RemoveAllEventHandlers();
    base.OnFormClosing(e);
}
```

Don't forget to add reference to `UIAutomationClient` and `UIAutomationTypes` assemblies and add `using System.Windows.Automation;`.

Comment: Don't forget to pin the delegate sent to SetWinEventHook via GCHandle.Alloc. Otherwise, the location can move in memory during a garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use user32.dll imports for this i would say.

Firstly, in your usings ensure you have:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Linq;
```

Then, in your class at the top insert this code to import methods from the DLL.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Now, in your own method, the following code should work:

```
        var _notepadProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses().Where(x => x.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("notepad")).DefaultIfEmpty(null).FirstOrDefault();
        if ( _notepadProcess != null )
        {
            var _windowHandle = FindWindow(null, "Page Setup");
            var _parent = GetParent(_windowHandle);
            if ( _parent == _notepadProcess.MainWindowHandle )
            {
                //We found our Page Setup window, and it belongs to Notepad.exe - yay!
            }
        }
```

This should get you started.

***** EDIT ******

Okay so you have got this:

```
mew.EventArrived += (sender, args) => { AppStarted(); };
```

This will ensure that the AppStarted() method gets fired when the notepad.exe process has started.

You then wait for 300ms (for some reason?!) and then call PopInFront:

```
async void AppStarted()
{         
    await Task.Delay(300);
    BeginInvoke(new System.Action(PoPInFront));
}
```

Inside PopInFront() you attempt to find the "Page Setup" window

```
var _windowHandle = FindWindow(null, "Page Setup");
```

However, my query here is: within the 0.3 seconds that have passed, can you safly say that you have been able to open notepad, wait for the GUI to init and navigate to the File -> Page Setup menu in .3 of a second for the next code area to find the window? - My guess is not, what you need here is a loop.

What you should be doing is:

1. WMI Query Event Fired
2. Start a background worker with a while loop that loops while the process notepad.exe is alive
3. In the while loop, keep checking for the Page Setup window
4. Once it's found, popup your own dialog, mark another variable to keep track that your dialog is shown
5. Once the page setup dialog is no longer shown (FindWindow will return zero), re-mark the variale in stage 4 and allow for the Page Setup window to be found again.

Comment: Nope,it doesn't find it sadly :( .And I added DLL's but forgot to add them here by stupidity ... And I have `Interop` and `Linq`

Comment: @JohnPietrar I wrote this code and tested it while writing it.  It found it all for me. - if you debug at what point does it fail?

Comment: I didn't say it fails. It executes my code when I open the `notepad` not the `Page Setup` window from the notepad.

Comment: @JohnPietrar Can we see your latest code? -- You should not be using WMI at all any more like in your initial code base posted :)

Comment: @JohnPietrar - I have updated this answer with an Edit, please check it out :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126730/discussion-between-mark-phillips-and-john-pietrar).