# How to find out what IWin32Window has been created when SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault throws an InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, winforms

After major refactoring, I run my WinForms application and it immediately crashes on `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false)`. In general, I understand what causes this: an `IWin32Window` has already been created.

My problem is that for the life of me I can't figure out what such an object (or objects?) have been instantiated. "Where" it was instantiated comes as a hopefully easier later question :) The line that throws is literally the second line of my code: if I step into my application (launching with F10 rather than F5, to be clear), it goes through the usual `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` without trouble, then it stops on the second line.

Is there a way to "inspect" created windows? I'm looking for any solution, lines of code, debugger features, external programs, anything. Thank you.

*PLEASE NOTE* that it's evident to me that I must have messed something up during my refactoring. I couldn't compile for three days, so it's most likely that I created the bug myself. I'm asking whether there's a way to confidently find the offending `IWin32Window` object.

**UPDATE**

I've added the following code at the very beginning of `Program.Main()`:

```
        var thisProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        if (thisProcess != null)
        {
            var mainWindow = thisProcess.MainWindowHandle;
        }
```

Well, `mainWindow` is (a pointer to) zero.

Comment: Probably you can listen to `EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE` event using Using `SetWinEventHook` method. Also probably you can handle Windows UI Automation events. Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40285043/3110834).

Comment: Not a lot of ways to get this wrong.  Except one.  My crystal ball tells me that you added a `static` variable to your Program class with a field initializer.  Something like `public static Form1 MainWindow = new Form1();`  That gets executed first, the debugger won't show it when you single-step.  Don't do that.

Comment: @HansPassant ha, I wish! :) I put breakpoints in most of my forms' constructors, but still no luck. And I have but two static variables (I know, I shouldn't do that, but it's legacy code I didn't write, and refactoring that is still in the backlog), and none apparently instantiates any form.

Comment: @RezaAghaei thanks for the pointer - I'm going to try that.

Comment: Use Debug > New Breakpoint > Function Breakpoint > type System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.AddWindowToTable.  Disable the "Just My Code" option with Tools > Options > Debugging so the breakpoint can work.

Comment: @HansPassant great tip! I found the offending Form: I'm relieved to say that it's a commit by a colleague :) It's a static Form that's a member of a member of a member... of a static object of `Program`'s. Please write a response with the breakpoint suggestion: I'll gladly mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to look for code that runs *before* your Main() method runs.  Not a lot of candidates for such code, only the static constructor (aka type initializer) for the Program class qualifies.  You'd know if you had written one, and could set a breakpoint on it, the less obvious case is a `static` variable in the Program class with a field initializer.  Not actually supported by the CLR, the C# compiler works around it by creating that static constructor itself and moving the code of the field initializer.

If knowing that it is caused by a field initializer doesn't help then you can consider setting a breakpoint on the relevant framework method.  That does require some insight in how it works internally and there is no simple shortcut for that.  Well, other than asking at SO :)

First use Tools > Options > Debugging > General and untick "Just My Code".  This isn't your code.  Next use Debug > New Breakpoint > Function Breakpoint > type "System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.AddWindowToTable".  That is the internal method that stores a reference to any created window, ensuring that the .NET class wrapper object does not get garbage collected too early.

Press F5, the Call Stack window points at the evil-doer.