# Accessing a WPF or WinForm Element From a Different Appdomain

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I want to create an application that will run in the background and track the click actions of the mouse, and when the user clicks on an external WPF or Winforms app, the background app should be able to detect the clicked control and display its ID/name/text.

I'm not sure if this is possible, but since there are automation tools that can perform similar actions, I think it should be possible. For example, with some tools it is possible to get the "window" object using the external app's PID, and then the controls (for example a button) can be accessed by providing the ID of the control. However in my case it is the other way around. I need to get ID/name/text of the control the user has clicked.

- I can obtain the mouse position using windows Hook
- I can obtain the hwnd and Process ID of the window the user has clicked

So is it possible to obtain the information about the element clicked? Any help and advice is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: This may help: [Detect when a specific window in another process opens or closes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40285043/3110834)

Comment: @RezaAghaei thanks for the reply. However, I tried both of the solutions provided in that answer and could not achieve my purpose. First, for the WinEventHook one: I tried the EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED event constant but it did not have any effect, the WinEventProc function never ran (sould I use another event? I could not see a useful one for my problem). Second, for the System.Windows.Automation one: Again I wasn't able to find a useful event type for my problem. I would appreciate it if you could provide more information if you know.